# Using null-loader to remove unneeded fonts in Webpack

Tags: css, webpack

I'm using FontAwesome and other font packages which include eot, ttf, svg fonts. I don't want to package them so I've got something like that in Webpack:

```
            /*
             * Load fonts from URL
             */
            {
                test: /\.(png|woff|woff2)(\?.*$|$)/,
                loader: 'file-loader'
            },

            /*
             * Remove outdated fonts
             */
            {
                test: /\.(eot|ttf|svg)(\?.*$|$)/,
                loader: 'null-loader'
            },
```

And then in main.css I got something like this:

```
url(fee66e712a8a08eef5805a46892932ad.woff) format("woff"),
url([object Object]) format("truetype"),
url([object Object]#fontawesomeregular) format("svg");
```

Which is not valid I believe and I don't see any FontAwesome icons. Is there a way to acheive it with Webpack?

Comment: That looks like it is including your font-awesome (but as a hashed name) and exluding all ttf and svg (putting in an empty object instead)

Comment: Yep, [hash].woff is what I want. But seems that url([object Object])  is breaking something and that's why I don't see any icons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At last I found a solution. Which is best described [here](https://medium.com/@modex13/webpack-2-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D1%8B-%D1%88%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%84%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%85-%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2-f5bbea0298e5)

To ignore some fonts and still have proper CSS one need to combine ignore-loader which returns empty string + raw-loader which returns contents but not object.

```
        {
            // Ignore fonts
            test: /\.(eot|ttf|svg)(\?.*$|$)/,
            use: ['raw-loader', 'ignore-loader']
        },
```

Comment: The non-deprecated equivalent to `raw-loader` in Webpack 5 is `asset/source`. I haven't yet tested that it still works, but the Webpack docs say it replaces `raw-loader`.

Comment: Unfortunately this solution no longer seems to work with Webpack 5, regardless of loader - at least when using `mini-css-extract-plugin`. I guess because `null-loader` is deprecated, even though the loader's docs page doesn't mention that. https://webpack.js.org/blog/2020-10-10-webpack-5-release/#deprecated-loaders

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to support woff you can use the `url-loader`

```
{
  // Match woff2 in addition to patterns like .woff?v=1.1.1.
  test: /\.(woff|woff2)(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
  loader: 'url-loader',
  options: {
    // Limit at 50k. Above that it emits separate files
    limit: 50000,

    // url-loader sets mimetype if it's passed.
    // Without this it derives it from the file extension
    mimetype: 'application/font-woff',

    // Output below fonts directory
    name: './fonts/[name].[ext]',
  },
},
```

Comment: Yes, but for example FontAwesome and other font packages _already_ referenced eot, ttf, svg. And when I simply ignore that fact I got an error in Webpack that it doesn't know how to handle svg for example. That's why I wanted to redirect svg to null-loader which causes css issues I think.